# net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException: The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must pass in exactly the sessions required to sign the transaction

Tags: corda

I'm trying to follow a corda tutorial but I don't understand where I'm wrong...
The unit test is run successfuly, but when I try to issue new IOU via api, the exception is thrown.
This is my flow code of IOU.
The exception is in the title, thanks in advance.

```
        //get notary reference
        final Party notary = getServiceHub().getNetworkMapCache().getNotaryIdentities().get(0);

        //builder
        final TransactionBuilder builder = new TransactionBuilder(notary);

        final List<PublicKey> partiesKey = this.state.getParticipants()
                .stream().map(AbstractParty::getOwningKey)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //create new issue command
        final Command<IOUContract.Commands.Issue> cmd = new Command<>(
                new IOUContract.Commands.Issue(), partiesKey
                );

        //create a transaction state
        TransactionState<IOUState> txState = new TransactionState<>(this.state,
                IOUContract.IOU_CONTRACT_ID, notary);

        //add to builder command and state
        builder.withItems(cmd, txState);

        //verify sign it
        builder.verify(getServiceHub());

        // Sign the transaction.
        final Party me = getOurIdentity();

        final SignedTransaction ptx = getServiceHub().signInitialTransaction(builder, me.getOwningKey());

        List<Party> otherParties = this.state.getParticipants().stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getOwningKey() != me.getOwningKey())
                .map(el -> (Party)el)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        //open flow session with other parties
        List<FlowSession> sessions = otherParties.stream()
                .map(el -> initiateFlow(el))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        SignedTransaction fullSign = subFlow(
            new CollectSignaturesFlow(
                ptx,
                sessions,
                ImmutableList.of(me.getOwningKey()),
                CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker()
            )
        );

        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullSign, sessions));
```

If I change code in the last 3 lines:

**FROM**

```
//open flow session with other parties
    List<FlowSession> sessions = otherParties.stream()
            .map(el -> initiateFlow(el))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    SignedTransaction fullSign = subFlow(
        new CollectSignaturesFlow(
            ptx,
            sessions,
            ImmutableList.of(me.getOwningKey()),
            CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker()
        )
    );

    return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullSign, sessions));
```

**TO**

```
//open flow session with counter party
        FlowSession lenderFlow = initiateFlow(state.getLender());

        SignedTransaction fullSign = subFlow(
            new CollectSignaturesFlow(
                ptx,
                ImmutableSet.of(lenderFlow),
                ImmutableList.of(me.getOwningKey()),
                CollectSignaturesFlow.Companion.tracker()
            )
        );

        return subFlow(new FinalityFlow(fullSign, ImmutableSet.of(lenderFlow)));
```

It's work correctly, WHY? what's the difference?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't by mistake try to issue an IOU to yourself? In that scenario the lender and borrower are the same so `otherParties` will be empty and `CollectSingaturesFlow` will throw the error. You might be passing both borrower and lender as the same value in your API.

Comment: No, the lender and borrower is not the same party...
In otherParties variable I exclude "me" and take all other parties on the transaction.
Party A are requesting IOU at Party B.

Comment: Put breakpoints on your code and check the values of `borrower` and `lender`. You can enable remote debugging with [this](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/node-commandline.html#enabling-remote-debugging).

Answer (score 0):

I believe Adel is right that you're passing the wrong parties to the collectSignatures subflow.

I'd double-check the contents of that list to make sure that the node running the flow isn't in that list.

Just a simple check or something like this will do it:

```
    //Collect all of the required signatures from other Players / Corda nodes using the CollectSignaturesFlow
    for (int i = 0; i < input.getPlayers().length; i++) {
        Party p = input.getPlayers()[i];

        if (p.equals(me)) {
            continue;
        }

        FlowSession session = initiateFlow(p);

        new IdentitySyncFlow.Send(session, partStx.getTx());

        sessionList.add(session);
    }
```